# yii class is not loading

Tags: php, yii

While trying to include my own class library in `Yii`. I used this code to include a class file in `Yii`.

```
Yii::import('application.apis.myapi.*');
```

myfile lies at `[protected/apis/myapi.php]`

I don't know I am getting this error:

```
[YiiBase::include(myapi.php) [<a href='function.YiiBase-include'>function.YiiBase-include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should import as

```
Yii::import('application.apis.*');
```

It will import all php files under directory **applications/apis/**.

```
Yii::import('application.apis.myapi'); //only one file
```

**EDIT**: also check this question: [Yii import functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729504/yii-import-functionality)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you override `basePath` for your application? (look at `protected/config/main.cfg`)