# Yii import functionality

Tags: php, include, yii

In my main config i have:

```
'import' => array(
'application.models.*',
'application.components.*',
```

I read somewhere that Yii import only calls the relevant class when needed.
Wanted to know if it's true and if importing all the folder at once is good practice in Yii.
Thanks,
Danny

Comment: Yup. That's true. So it hardly matters even if you include the whole folder (in theory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the import call, when you pass in a folder like 'application.models.*', what Yii does, its add that path to the php include_path, so that when you call a class contained in that folder, if the Yii autoloader fails php looks for that class in the include path, thats fast.

If you include a file like 'application.models.FormModel', then Yii autoloader is aware of it and also loads the class on deman only.

you can find more information on the Yii guide: [importing classes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace#importing-classes)